# Passing image between views when pushing button

Tags: iphone, xcode, image, sdk

I'm searching for passing an image who depend of the choice of button.
I have Button1, Button2, Button3 on my FirstController.

I'd like when i push on Button1, image named photo.png display on SecondController into Imageview already insert in my view.
The same if i push on button2, image named photo2.png display on the same Imageview.
I don't really know how to do what I want.
I'd like to insert the image's passing into this code :

```
- (IBAction)Button1:(id)sender {
    SecondController *dvController = [[SecondController alloc] 
initWithNibName:@"SecondController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    dvController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentModalViewController:dvController animated:YES];
    [dvController release];
    dvController = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`SecondController` should have a `property` like `UIImage* previousViewImage` that you can pass from the sender as `dvController.previousViewImage= [(UIButton*)sender imageForState:UIControlStateNormal].`

Answer (score 0):

One way is to have an array of image names, then use the tag of the button as the index to get the image name from the array.

You start by having one button and one IBAction linked to it. Then copy and paste the buttons. This gives you a number of buttons but one piece of code. A different tag property is set for each button and the code uses [sender tag] as the index to the array.

The dvController then has a UIImage property which is set from this array, prior to being presented. In dvController's viewWillAppear, the UIImageView is then set to the UIImage passed across.

Answer (score 0):

hey tom john what you can do is that in your SecondController.h declare and synthesize a string , so when the first button is pressed you can set the value of the string with the name of the image you want to set in the second view controller 's image view in your method as

```
 - (IBAction)Button1:(id)sender {
SecondController *dvController = [[SecondController alloc]
```

initWithNibName:@"SecondController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
dvController.imageName=@"photo", // imageName is the string which you will declare in your  second view controller
    dvController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentModalViewController:dvController animated:YES];
    [dvController release];
    dvController = nil;
}

and in the second view controller's view did load you can do this

```
imageView.image=[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:imageName ofType:@"png"]];//  imageview is the name of your imageview outlet .
```

and similarly for the second button you can set the `dvController.imageName=@"photo2"// put the name without png` . hope this helps.